# How to pass a XML group as parameter from jasper to java

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm trying to pass a XML group content (I'm using XML as datasource) as a parameter to a java method, I need to get this group in java class, format the tags information (name1 + name2 + name3.....nameN) and return it to the JRXML TextField.
I can do it for a simple XML tag, but when I try to do it with a group, It appear as null in java method:
My XML:

```
<Group1>
    <Group2>
        <Person>
        <Name>John</Name>
        </Person>
        <Person>
        <Name>Mary</Name>
        </Person>
        <Person>
        <Name>Joseph</Name>
        </Person>
    </Group2>
</Gropup1>
```

My JRXML fields declaration:

```
<field name="group1.group2" class="java.lang.Object">
         <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Group1/Group2]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="group1.group2.person" class="java.lang.Object">
         <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Group1/Group2/Person]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="group1.group2.person.name" class="java.lang.String">
         <fieldDescription><![CDATA[Group1/Group2/Person/Name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

My JRML textField Expression:

```
<textFieldExpression   class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[com.foo.report.MyReport.formatNames($F{group1.group2.person})]]></textFieldExpression>
```

My method signature:
    public static String formatNames(Object person) {...}

Debugging the "formatNames" method, the parameter "person" appear as null.

If I change the parameter of textFieldExpression to the field group1.group2 it appear as null too.

If I change the parameter of textFieldExpression to the field group1.group2.person.name it appear the String in the java debug: "John".

The goal is format the names list to show as: "John - Mary - Joseph" in the textFieldExpression, if someone have another way to do it, please, tell me.
Thank you

Comment: Do you have to use an XML data source? If you have a collection of Java objects, you can wrap them in a bean collection data source. Then you can use dot notation to get the values.

Comment: Hi Dave, I thought of doing this, but I would like to avoid the XML transformation in bean, is there any way to pass the XML group to java without having to transform it?

Comment: And you read the fine [manual](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xmldatasource/)?